# Checkbox are not checking using iTextSharp in PDF

Tags: asp.net, pdf, c#-4.0, itext, pdf-generation

Hi I am trying to check the checkboxes in the pdf (which has 4 check boxes) but only first check box is checking and others are not. Below are the fields in pdf form for check boxes

```
topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[0];

topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[1];

topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[2];

topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[3];
```

When I use the below code

```
formFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[0]", "1");
```

First checkbox is checked in pdf form. But similar way below code doesn't check the other checkboxes

```
formFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[1]", "1");

formFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[2]", "1");

formFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[3]", "1");
```

Any ideas? Please help me.

Comment: finally got the answer. the correct code for other check boxes isformFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[1]", "2");

formFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[2]", "3");

formFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[3]", "4");

Comment: String[] checkboxstates1 = formFields.GetAppearanceStates("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[1]"); by using this we would know what would be the possible value for checkbox

Comment: Please make the solution an actual answer and accept it as soon as you are allowed to (AFAIK you cannot immediately accept your own answers).

Answer (score 2):

Finally got the answer. The correct code for other check boxes is

```
formFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[1‌​]", "2");
formFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[2]"‌​, "3");
formFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[3]"‌​, "4");

String[] checkboxstates = formFields.GetAppearanceStates("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c‌​1_01_0_[1]");
```

by using this we would know what would be the possible value for checkbox
is

```
formFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_01_0_[1‌​]", checkboxstates[0]);
```